# Can't open Scene Builder JavaFX

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

When I want to open Scene Builder it won't show. I tried double-click my .fxml file from NetBeans, double-click executable file and run it directly from terminal.

The error I get:

```
    kamil@kamil-System-Product-Name:~/JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0$ sudo ./JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0 
./JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0: 1: ./JavaFXSceneBuilder2.0: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

My Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

My NetBeans version: 8.0.2

Comment: What is your system?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0):

Since JDK8u40 scene builder is not included in Oracle Java

> Starting with Oracle Java SE 8u40, Oracle does not provide a separate
>   set of accompanying JavaFX Scene Builder binaries. If you would like
>   to contribute changes, ideas or just let us know what you have done
>   with the code, please consult the OpenJDK Community contribution
>   guidelines and join the openjfx-dev mailing list.

Try to download [Gluon Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/)

You can still download the last binary at Oracle in this link. But check this warning:

> WARNING: These versions of JavaFX Scene Builder may include components
>   that do not contain the latest security patches and are not
>   recommended for use in production.